# Import specific file from an S3 subfolder into Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am using boto library to import data from S3 into python following instructions: http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html

The following code allows me to import all files in main folder into python, but replacing c.get_bucket('mainfolder/subfolder') does not work. Does anybody knows how i can access a sub-folder and import its contents ?

```
import boto
c = boto.connect_s3()
b = c.get_bucket('mainfolder')
```

Comment: to browse the subfolders use "result_set = bckt_obj.list(s3_path, delimiter = '/')" which will return result set object then you can iterate this result set to get subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_bucket` method on the connection returns a `Bucket` object. To access individual files or directories within that bucket, you need to create a `Key` object with the file path, or use `Bucket.list_keys` with a folder path to get all the keys for files under that path. Each `Key` object acts as a handle for a stored file. You then call functions on the keys to manipulate the files stored. For example:

```
import boto

connection = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = connection.get_bucket('myBucketName')

fileKey = bucket.get_key('myFileName.txt')
print fileKey.get_contents_as_string()

for key in bucket.list('myFolderName'):
    print key.get_contents_as_string()
```

The example here simply prints out the contents of each file (which is probably a bad idea!). Depending on what you want to do with the files, you may want to download them to a temporary directory, or read them to a variable etc. See http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.key for the documentation on what can be done with keys.